# SpringBoot: Stereotype Annotations not working on Interface Level

Tags: spring-boot, components, stereotype

```
   package com.Test.springboot;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan({"com.Test.springboot"})
public class SpringBoot1Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBoot1Application.class, args);



    }

}
```

Controller Class

```
package com.Test.springboot;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import com.Test.springboot.model.Student;
import com.Test.springboot.model.StudentDao;

@Controller
public class StudentController {
    @Autowired
    private StudentDao studentDao;

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String homePage() {
        return "home";
    }
```

StudentDao

```
@Repository
public interface StudentDao {
    public Student addStudent(Student student);
    public Student getStudent(long id);
    public List<Student> getAllStudents();
    public String deleteStudent();

}
```

**If we change the stereotype(Repository) annotation to implementation class it's working fine. but Interface level throwing an error(org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.vitechinc.springboot.model.StudentDao' available:)**

Comment: Spring can't find an implementation for your bean,  you have to provide an implementation for this interface with a stereotype annotation, or you can extend `JpaRepository` (or `CrudRepository`...) in your `StudentDao` interface to tell Spring  it's a repository bean (`Spring Data`)

Answer (score 1):

Try adding below code as a maven dependancy in the `pom.xml` file:

I got the same issue and after installing this dependency now its working,

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.8</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: No, we can only use Lombok to generate the entity's constructor, getters, and setters. Hence, The issue will not be fixed by just adding Lombok dependency. There are many other issues in the code mentioned in the actual question.